# Why is Garbage Collection not happening for strings stored in memory for node 16?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, garbage-collection, v8

I have a memory leak in my `node.js` application causing the pods to crash. I noticed a surge in memory on concurrent hits and garbage collection happens to a certain level but when ideal the memory doesn't restore to the previous level. However, the memory leak is small and takes around 72 hours for the pods to crash which happens when it reaches to `1.1 GB`. Ideally, the memory utilisation shouldn't be more than `40MB`, and during peak hours surge is normal but it restores back to around `40MB` when idle.

We didn't have any such issue with `node version 12` but with `node 16` we are facing a memory leak issue.

I took a heap snapshot before starting the test and once the test was done left it idle for garbage collection to happen, then again took another heap snapshot.

Before:
[image]

`(string)` takes around `13988028`

`(compiled code)` takes around `12948428`

before the test, the data in the string looked like this

[image]

After:
[image]

`(string)` takes around `61617524`

`(compiled code)` takes around `67697612`

Also compiled code contains reference of string.

And after the test, the `HTML` page content is added to a string that is not being garbage collected. It also contains some `500` error response HTML pages for which the request wasn't successful.

[image]

Can anyone please help with this issue?

Comment: This is definitely a bug somewhere. It can be in your code, in React, in the Node.js class library... First thing would be to use DevTools to check what references these strings. You can open those tabs and see who created them and if there are still references.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you know how to take and view heap snapshots for Node.js - that's great. One small detail, though:

> once the test was done left it idle for garbage collection to happen, then again took another heap snapshot

There's no need to wait, garbage collection happens automatically when taking a heap snapshot. Snapshot contains only live objects, no garbage.

In your case it is obviously that the memory leaks because HTML response pages are somehow accumulated in memory. How to prove this:

- start the server
- monitor the amount of `"<!DOCTYPE HTML>..."` strings in memory, e.g. via the heap snapshots or via [queryObjects](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#queryObjects-function) command in DevTools
- the amount should increase while more and more user requests are processed

The next step for you is to analyse this snapshot.

Select the first of leaked strings and look through its [retaining tree](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/memory-problems/memory-101/#objects_retaining_tree). Repeat for the next few strings. You need to find some object that holds references to your HTML strings in itself, maybe through a long chain of intermediate objects. That could be in-memory cache built over Map, or a collection of server requests/responses, or closures with function created on each request, or even a 3rd party [library](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fixing-a-memory-leak-in-a-production-node-js-app#not-quite-finished). Skimming through all the leaked strings you inevitably will notice some repeating pattern in their retaining trees and understand who and why holds those objects in memory.

You could train first on live examples of memory leaks

- leaks in [browser code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/memory-problems/heap-snapshots)
- leak in [React app](https://codesandbox.io/s/autobind-debounce-memory-leak-jezks?file=/src/Child.js)
- leak in [Node.js code](https://nodesource.com/blog/memory-leaks-demystified)
- another example of leak in [Node.js code](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-memory-leaks-node-js-apps/)
- leak example from [Meteor.js](https://point.davidglasser.net/2013/06/27/surprising-javascript-memory-leak.html)

After training finding the actual leak will go easier and faster.